# How to Map Network Drives Using Logon Scripts & Group Policy Objects?

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory

I want to know how do I map network drives using the logon script method and the group policy objects method? If anyone could post me a in depth answer for going about these methods and explaining the reasoning behind it in a easy to understand I would really appreciate that. Thanks and I look forward to hearing from you!

P.S. I'm also using Windows Server 2012 r2

Comment: I'm sorry, this site is not a tutorials site. There's plenty of documentation and examples on the internet. Google it and go learn how to do this.

Comment: Just as important, learn when you need to do this and how to avoid it.

Comment: Look under the "Preferences" section of your Group Policy editor...

Answer (score 1):

Use the Net command in your logon script.  Example:

NET USE P: \\dfsroot\path\to\folder

The GPO for drive maps is at User Configuration/Preferences/Windows Settings/Drive maps